# Do strings used in API version 4 need to be escaped?

Tags: wordpress, api, apiv4

When running something like this:

```
$result = civicrm_api4('Event', 'get', [
    'select' => ['id'],
    'where' => [
        ['OR', [
                ['title', 'LIKE', $keyword],
                ['summary', 'LIKE', $keyword],
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'checkPermissions' => false,
]);
```

Should the `$keyword` variable be escaped or is it something done internally by the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all strings will be escaped automatically by the CiviCRM code.